# PID Control Lithium-Ion Batteries

Tags: batteries, charger, lithium-ion, pid-controller

Please help in finding good literature/articles about PID Control for Li-Ion Batteries. I searched the internet but I heardly find anything. There are a lot of articles regarding motor control design, however no battery chargers.
The literature especially should handle control design regarding parameters choice based on battery models.

1. Books
2. Master/Doctorial Thesis
3. IEEE articles
4. Application Notes

Where you have found them useful. Will be highly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: What do you exactly want to control? Charge? Discharge? Is heat a factor?

Comment: We don't google for you, thats *your* job Please see: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They basically use threshold control with some hysteresis for LiPo chargers.

- Phase 1 Check Voc and temp as each parameter is Temp compensated.
- Phase 2 Check Vbat with load for Drop in voltage and charge slow if V<3V due to high ESR
  -Phase 3 If above 3V to 3.2V (approx) apply constant current according to Mfg specs  at Constant Current C1 or other...
- Phase 4 When Vcv threshold is reached go into CV mode, ( usually 4.2V but can be higher at low currents. )
- Phase 5 When Ich drops below 10% approx of CC rate, then shut-off charger and go to Vfloat mode at 3.7 to 3.9V

So there is no PID gain feedback as it is non-linear.